# User let with arguments

Tags: rspec

I want to test this class:

```
class Response

  def initialize(raw_response:)
     ........
  end
end
```

I want to send multiple raw_responses in rspec. I implemented this code:

```
  let(:successful_response)    { File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', 'successful_response.xml')) }
  ......
  let(:response)               { described_class.new(raw_response: file_name) }

  context '#response' do

    it 'submits response' do 

      let(:file_name) { :successful_response }              
      expect(:response(raw_response: :file_name).parse_response).to include(................)
    end
  end
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
expect(:response(raw_response: :file_name).par...
                         ^
```

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
context 'when response is successful' do
  let(:file_name) { successful_response } 
  it 'submits response' do              
    expect(response.parse_response).to include(...)
  end
end

context 'when response is unsuccessful' do
  let(:file_name) { 'bad.xml' } 
  it 'submits response' do              
    expect(response.parse_response).to include(...)
  end
end
```

Don't use `let` inside `it/specify` - it won't work. If you need to change the value for a different context - use `context`.

You can think about `let` like defining a memoized method.

```
let(:response) { described_class.new(raw_response: filename) }
let(:filename) { :foo }
```

is like

```
def response 
  described_class.new(raw_response: filename)
end

def filename
  :foo
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer solves several formatting issues all at once, but just want to point out that the specific error OP got:

> `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
>   expect(:response(raw_response: :file_name).par...`

is because `:response` is a `Symbol`, not something you can pass arguments to, so the `(` is unexpected.

If you did actually want to test something about a `Symbol` it can work, but it's still important to note that this would just literally be testing the symbol itself, and not the `let` variable.

`expect(:request).to be_a(Symbol)`

`response` without the `:` is how to access the variable created by the `let`:

`expect(response.parse_response).to include(...)`